# String Array null check fails

Tags: java, arrays, servlets

I have values coming from Servlet and one of the parameter I am receiving as

```
request.getParameterValues("Names");
```

I am assigning it to

```
  String names[] = null;
  names =  request.getParameterValues("Names");
```

I am checking whether names is null by the following manner, however even it is null, my condition is not getting executed. What could be the reason for this?

```
if(names!= null)
```

Comment: "*however even it is null, my condition is not getting executed*" - That's what supposed to happen, you wrote `if(names != null)`.

Comment: What's the point of assigning null to the variable, and to reassign a new value right after? Why not simply use `String[] names = request.getParameterValues("Names")`?

Comment: is `request.getParameterValues("Names");` returns a `String` array?

Comment: @Sam: if it wasn't, the code would not compile. See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Otherwise check whether the parameter name that you have passed matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is good to check `null` on parameter like `request.getParameterValues("Names")`

```
String names[] = null;
if(request.getParameterValues("Names")!=null){
  names =  request.getParameterValues("Names");
}
```

Comment: I have a check condition as `if (request.getParameterValues("Names") == null) {
System.out.println("Names is null ");
            }
            else if(request.getParameterValues("Names")!= null){
                names = request.getParameterValues("Names");
                System.out.println("Namesis not null  ");
                            }` Even if Names parameter is null, it doesn't execute `System.out.println("Names is null ");`. What could be the reason?

Comment: can you printing `request.getParameterValues("Names")` and what you get, better try like `System.out.println("-"+request.getParameterValues("Names")+"-"+)`

Comment: Sorry it is printing as `-[Ljava.lang.String;@8eaf4-`

Comment: The issue is in URL I have `?Names=` If there is no equal then it executes `System.out.println("Names is null ");` If there is = then it prints as `-[Ljava.lang.String;@8eaf4-`

Comment: so it has one parameter?!, whats the size of `names[]` then

Comment: There was a bug in my code which prevented the null check, it is working fine now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

> I am checking whether names is null

so it should be `if(names == null)`